# Show that if $n ≡ 7 \pmod{12}$ then $n ≡3\pmod 4$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

*My attempt*

$n = 7 + 12k$

$n = 3+4j$

I'm stuck here, I can't see any relation to prove this.

Comment: $7+12k=3+4+4\cdot 3k = 3+4\cdot (\dots)$

Comment: we get 12k+7=4j+3;  12k+4=4j; 4(3k+1)=4j; j=3k+1;

Comment: $n\equiv a\pmod{\!4k}\,\Rightarrow\, n\equiv a\pmod{\!4},\,$ i.e. congruences *persist* mod factors of the modulus.

Comment: @BillDubuque But in my case $n ≡ 7$ and $\ n ≡ 3$, the a is different.

Comment: @hjx  $\ n\equiv 7\pmod{\!12}\,\Rightarrow\, n\equiv 7\ [\equiv 3]\pmod{\!4}\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $n\equiv 7\pmod {12}$. Then we have
$$\exists k\in\Bbb Z:n-7=12k\implies n=12k+7\implies n=(4)(3k)+(3+4)\implies n=4(3k+1)+3$$
and thus $n=4j+3$ with $j=3k+1$. Hence, $n\equiv 3\pmod{4}$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: we can write $$n=3+4+4\cdot 3k$$

Answer (score 1):

If
$$n\equiv3\pmod 4$$
then
$$\boxed{3n\equiv9\pmod {12}}$$
Also if you sum
$$n\equiv 7 \pmod {12}$$
$$n\equiv 7 \pmod {12}$$
$$n\equiv 7 \pmod {12}$$
You'll get
$$n+n+n\equiv7+7+7\pmod {12}$$
which is
$$3n\equiv 21 \pmod {12}$$
and
$$\boxed{3n\equiv 9 \pmod {12}}$$

Comment: If you intend to later apply the first sentence to finish what's below then you need the *reverse* inference $\,3n\equiv 9\pmod{12}\Rightarrow\, n\equiv 3\pmod{4}.\,$ You are essentially using $\ 12\mid m\,\Rightarrow\,12\mid 3m\,\Rightarrow\, 4\mid m\,$ instead of the simpler $\,4\mid 12\mid m.\ $ In total, you are multiplying by $3$ then later cancelling $3,\,$ but neither is necessary. Is there some reason your prefer that method, vs. using transitivity of divisibility?